# How can I select outermost tag which contains img as direct child

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have following markup

```js
var divs = $('div:has(img)').not(':parent:has(>img)');

divs.css('border','1px solid red');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><!-- get this div -->
  1
  <img alt='#' />
  <div>
    2
    <img alt='#' />
    <div>
      3
      <img alt='#' />
      <div>
        4
        <img alt='#' />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div><!-- get this div -->
  5
  <img alt='#' />
  <div>
    6
    <img alt='#' />
  </div>

  <div>
    7
    <img alt='#' />
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <div><!-- get this div -->
    8
    <img alt='#' />
  </div>
</div>
```

From this I need to select the outermost div which contains img tag, that I don't want to select div if it's parent contains `img` tag as direct child. I have tried `var divs = $('div:has(img)').not(':parent:has(>img)');` but it only works when it's have a parent.

Comment: Why aren't you using classes?

Comment: @zzzzBov :  I know how to do it with class, but I need to know is that possible with any css or jQuery selector

Comment: @PranavCBalan Close, but not optimized. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/vvL41vyc/)

Comment: OR [`$('div img:only-child').each(function () {
    $(this).parents('div:has(> img)').last().addClass('hello');
});`](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/vvL41vyc/1/)

Comment: @Tushar :  that's what I want :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main problem is the fact that `:parent` selector does not do what you think it does. CSS rules never go upwards. So if you need to go upwards, you need to do this using JavaScript (using the function `.parent()`, which does not have an equivalent in CSS selectors, not even jQuery extended ones).

```
var divs = $('div:has(>img)').filter(function(i, n) { return !($(n).parent().children('img').length); });
divs.css('color','red');
```

However, this will paint *everything* red, because of the first C in CSS ("cascading"): the declaration of colour red on 1, 5 and 8 will paint all text inside those divs red.